# Fast substring search in a large text database?

Tags: python, pandas, elasticsearch, bigdata

I have a box of disk drives that contains backups of work and personal files over many years. Most of the files and directories are duplicates of other backups on other disks, or even on the same disk.

To consolidate this mess, I have created a csv file having the checksum, size and full path of each file. I then wrote a simple Python program using the pandas library to compute a checksum and size for each directory, which is simply the sum of the checksums and sizes of all files contained in the directory. The idea is to find all directories with identical content and delete all of them but one.

Unfortunately (but I expected this before) the code runs a few hours even for my test data set which has about 1 million rows. The actual data set has about 10 million rows.

Here is the python code fragment:

```
# for all directories, compute their checksum and total content size

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['cksum', 'len', 'path'])
i = 0

for path in directories:

    # create new dataframe having all files in this directory
    items = data[data['path'].str.startswith(path)]

    # sum all checksums
    cksum = pd.to_numeric(items['cksum']).sum()

    # sum all file sizes
    len = pd.to_numeric(items['len']).sum()

    # store result 
    df.loc[i] = [cksum, len, path]

    i += 1
```

Obviously, the problem is that for each directory I have to find contained directories and files, and to identify those I do a startswith(path) string comparison, which is slow and I need to run this 1 (or 10) million times for each directory. So we have an O(n^2) type of problem here.

I understand that my current algorithm is naive and I could come up with a much better one, but before investing time here I would like to learn whether a different approach might be more worthwile:

- Should I rather use a SQL database here? Think of a statement
  similar to `SELECT cksum, len, path FROM files,directories WHERE leftstr(files.path,n) == directories.path;`. But maybe this statement
  is just as expensive as its python equivalent?
- Is a different database or tool more suitable for this kind of text search? I was thinking of Apache Lucene, ElasticSearch, MongoDB, NOSQL but I have no experience with these to decide which product to try.
- Maybe somebody else solved this deduplication problem already? I found a
  few commercial PC software products but I am not sure if they can handle 10 million files.

Please advise.

Comment: This is a problem solved by de-duplicating software and filesystems and writing your own version may be overkill and less efficient overall. I've used fdupes before which works well but even so be aware it isn't unusual for the operation you're trying to do to take a very long time. Having said that you'll probably only need to do it once so runtime shouldn't be something you need to care about that much.

Comment: I should also warn you that summing checksums and lengths in no way guarantees that 2 completely different directories won't accidentally collide. The chance might be low but it isn't zero.

Comment: yes I'm aware that my sum is not a proper checksum. However I am primarily interested in whether a SQL select (or a different text search tool) would be significantly faster than my python code.